# Order elements of sublist via another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

Let's say I have the following lists of lists:

```
lst=[['A'],['B'],['C'],['D']]
lst2=[['C','D','B'],['D','C'],['D','B','A']]
```

And I need to order each sublist of `lst2` by the order of appearance of elements from the first list. Thus, `lst2` should ultimately be:

```
Result=['B','C','D'],['C','D'],['A','B','D']]
```

I know I could use for loops that iterate over `lst2` and compare each element with the element of `lst`, then create a new list that saves every element whenever those match, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this

Comment: Why is `lst` a list of single-element lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First flatten lst:

```
lst = [e for ele in lst for e in ele]
```

Then sort each element using lst.index as key:

```
lst2 = [sorted(i, key = lst.index) for i in lst2]
```

Comment: Good with one small issue -- you are assuming that only one element in lst sublist. so flattening is not 100% correct

Comment: True, i did assume that. I changed to your flatten.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[['A'],['B'],['C'],['D']]
lst2=[['C','D','B'],['D','C'],['D','B','A']]

lst1 = [e for ele in lst for e in ele] # flatten the lst
Result = []
for arr in lst2:
    Result.append([ele for ele in lst1 if ele in arr])
```

One Assumption that you do not have duplicates in lst2 sublist